# Azure AD B2C Password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a .net core Web api which is using Azure AD B2C for Authentication and Authorization.
By default Azure trims any space the user enters before or after the password in the blue login page.
There is a requirement from our clients that they don't want the the space to be trimmed (meaning if the user enter extra space before or after password, they should be shown "Password is wrong") 
I wanted to know if there is any way to achieve this in custom policy.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the custom policies you can achieve this. Azure AD B2C supports configuration options to control the complexity of passwords that customers can use. You can define password complexity by using `DisallowedWhitespace` predicate element

```
 <Predicate Id="DisallowedWhitespace" Method="MatchesRegex" HelpText="The password must not begin or end with a whitespace character.">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Id="RegularExpression">(^\S.*\S$)|(^\S+$)|(^$)</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Predicate>
```

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/predicates#configure-password-complexity)